# zend framework: how to prepare and execute WHERE IN clause?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo

I want to prepare a statement for use inside a loop. When I try to execute the statement I see an error in the logs saying "Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound'".

What's wrong with my code?

```
$itemSelectSql = "SELECT * FROM `tblItems` WHERE `itemID` IN (?)";
$itemSelectStmt = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($this->db_ro, $itemSelectSql);
while () {
  ...
  $itemIds = array();
  // populate $itemIds array
  ...
  $itemSelectStmt->execute(array($itemIds));
}
```

EDIT:

I think I may have a bug in my set up which explains why whatever I try fails. I'm seeing this:

```
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, 
class 'PDOStatement' does not have a method 'bind_param' in 
/var/www/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php on line 204
```

EDIT:

I was using the wrong adapter. Should have been Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo :-)

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Paul, test performance both with generating multiple `?` (as suggested by @cwallenpoole) and with using `FIND_IN_SET()` (as suggested by me). Although I noted in my answer that "*I'm not sure if it has any impact on performance*", it was not meant as "*it probably has negative impact*". In fact, it even might have a positive impact, if MySQL caches statements (with `FIND_IN_SET()`, you will always have the same statement, while with multiple `?` statements will vary) and if `strlist` argument of `FIND_IN_SET()` is parsed only once for query rather than for each row.

Comment: Sorry, I've gone with the other solution since I'm more familiar with it and need to crack on. Thanks though.

Comment: Paul, I took a look at output of `explain`, and it looks like `find_in_set()` is not able to use indexes, so "the other solution" will probably perform better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`?` can't be replaced by an array, it has to be replaced by a scalar (thanks to comment for pointing out that this does not always mean string... brain-fart on my end). Let me know if this works better:

```
$itemSelectSql = "SELECT * FROM `tblItems` WHERE `itemID` IN ";
while () {
  ...
  $itemIds = array();
  // populate $itemIds array
  ...
  // we need to have the same number of "?,"'s as there are items in the array.
  // and then remove final comma.
  $qs = rtrim(str_repeat("?,", count($itemIds)),',');
  // create a statement based on the result
  $itemSelectStmt = 
       new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($this->db_ro, "$itemSelectSql ($qs)");
  // bind to each of those commas.
  $itemSelectStmt->execute($itemIds);
}
```

Comment: "*`?` can't be replaced by an array, it has to be replaced by a string." - it does not have to be replaced with a string. Zend documentation states that it can be any *scalar* value. PHP documentation of `is_scalar()` states that scalar types are strings as well as integers, floats and booleans.

Comment: I need to use prepared statements for performance reasons, but I could perhaps find an efficient implementation from your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid anymore with Zend 1.11. I'm able to do ->where('column IN (?)', $array) and it converts it to a proper IN clause just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this:

```
while () {
  ...
  $itemIds = array();
  // populate $itemIds array
  $itemIds = implode(',' $itemIds);
  $itemSelectStmt->execute(array($itemIds));
}
```

I'm not an expert of Zend_framework, but when you use statements, to the execute method you must

> If you use positional parameters, or
>   those that are marked with a question
>   mark symbol ('?'), pass the bind
>   values in a plain array.

So i think you need to pass an array with one value and that value replace the "?" in the statement. In this case you need a comma separated string (if you ids are int) to replace (?) in the statement.

What you do if you do not implode the values is passing an array containing an array.

Comment: Yes I've tried imploding the array. It still returns the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) instead of `IN ()`:

```
mysql> select id, name from customer where find_in_set(id, '10,15,20');
+----+---------+
| id | name    |
+----+---------+
| 10 | ten     |
| 15 | fifteen |
| 20 | twelve  |
+----+---------+
```

This way, you don't have to bind array with multiple values to `IN()`, you can pass list of IDs as a single comma-separated string. You can safely use PHP function `implode()` to generate string from array of IDs.

<s>Though, I'm not sure if it has any impact on performance.</s>
I took a look at output of `explain`, and it looks like `find_in_set()` is not able to use indexes, so generating queries with variable number of parameters should perform better.

Comment: I'm not familiar with find_in_set, but I'll EXPLAIN it and see how it compares to WHERE IN.